# How to disable mouse when cursor type is none and then enable when it is anything else e.g. Pointer

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi im pretty new to Javascript,

I need to disable my mouse when it has no cursor type and then reenable it when it becomes any other cursor type, how can i achieve this for my webpage? JS/CSS/HTML

Comment: `.someElement { cursor: none }` and then `.someElement:hover { cursor: pointer !important }`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on writing questions that best enable the community to help.  Typically, you'll want a clear explanation of the problem or what you are trying to achieve, including what you have tried in a [mcve], the expected result, the actual result, and how they differ.  Remember, a well-formed question is critical for the community to be able to provide specific, useful guidance. Good luck, and happy coding!